# Allow only one overlay in google maps api v3

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

my requirement is draw either `circular` or `polygon` overlays on `google maps`, I have done that but after drawing one overlay the user can draw another overlay, i want to prevent that when the user started second overlay of any type`(circular or polygon)` first overlay should be deleted or any other suggestions to achieve the functionality.

Comment: what you have tried so far...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't get any simpler than this: store your polygon in a variable after it has been added to the map and before adding new polygons you check this var and if it's not empty/null you remove it from the map with `poly.setMap(null)`.

Comment: I did that but it is after completion in overlay complete event how to track start of new polygon an trigger it